# How to set different colors on zoom control in amCharts map (v4)

Tags: maps, amcharts, amcharts4

By setting fill property we can set the background color property of the zoom controls, but the **button text color** is not a property we can set.

```
chart.zoomControl.plusButton.background.cornerRadius(5, 5, 5, 5);
chart.zoomControl.plusButton.background.fill = '#014888';
chart.zoomControl.plusButton.background.states.getKey('hover').properties.fill = '#27aad6';
```

Is there a choice to set it?

Answer (score 1):

I have set it by this way:

```
chart.zoomControl.plusButton.label.fill = '#ffffff';
chart.zoomControl.minusButton.label.fill = '#ffffff';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply achieve this like this if you are using am chart 5

Take the instance in new var then set all custom properties

```
const zoomControl = map.set("zoomControl", am5map.ZoomControl.new(root, {
          dy: -284,
          dx: -39,
        }));
        // map.zoomControl.plusButton.label.fill = '#ffffff';

        zoomControl.minusButton.setAll({
          stroke: am5.color(0xfff)
        });
        zoomControl.plusButton.setAll({
          stroke: am5.color(0xfff)
        });
        
        zoomControl.minusButton.get("background").setAll({
          fill: am5.color(0x262626),
          fillOpacity: 0.7,
          stroke: am5.color(0x111111),
          strokeWidth: 2,
          strokeOpacity: 0.3,
        });
        zoomControl.minusButton.get('background').states.create('hover', {}).setAll({
          fill: am5.color(0x000000),
          fillOpacity: 1,
        });
        
        zoomControl.minusButton.get('background').states.create('down', {}).setAll({
          fill: am5.color(0x666666),
          fillOpacity: 1,
        });        
        

        zoomControl.plusButton.get("background").setAll({
          fill: am5.color(0x262626),
          fillOpacity: 0.7,
          stroke: am5.color(0x111111),
          strokeWidth: 2,
          strokeOpacity: 0.3,
        });

        zoomControl.plusButton.get('background').states.create('hover', {}).setAll({
          fill: am5.color(0x000000),
          fillOpacity: 1,
        });
        
        zoomControl.plusButton.get('background').states.create('down', {}).setAll({
          fill: am5.color(0x666666),
          fillOpacity: 1,
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
chart.set("zoomControl", am5map.ZoomControl.new(root, {
     background: am5.Rectangle.new(root, {
         // fill: am5.color(0xeb354e),               
         fillOpacity: 0.9,
         strokeOpacity:0
     })
}));
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?